# Some errors spotted while using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsdate, nssortdescriptor

I have used NSSortDescriptor to sort my objects using date as key. My code:

```
 NSLog(@"Before sorting: %@", temp);
    NSSortDescriptor *dateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"date" ascending: YES];
    NSArray *sortedArray2 = [temp sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject: dateSortDescriptor]];
    NSLog(@"After sorting: %@", sortedArray2);
    NSMutableArray *afterSorting = [[(NSArray*)sortedArray2 mutableCopy]autorelease];
```

It worked well when the dates are

```
22/08/2012
23/08/2012
25/09/2012
```

However, I found that NSSortDescriptor only seemed to sort by the first two numbers in front because when my dates change a little, my result became like this:

```
10/09/2012
22/08/2012
23/08/2012
```

Can any one please advice? Saw many other posts using NSSortDescriptor as similar to my codes above but they seem to have no errors any where. For me, it only sort by the day but not the month! What I do is to sort objects with the nearer date on top. Thanks!

Comment: Is the value of the key "date" a date object or a string?

Comment: It's actually retrieved from a plist, a string. But I do not know how to convert it as NSdate. Hmm.. Care to share?:)

Comment: Do I get the string, convert to NSDate and then add it back into the array before sorting or??

Comment: It would be easiest to convert to dates then sort, and convert back to a string (if you need it to be a string). Otherwise, you would have to write a custom sorter.

Comment: The simplest solution is to code your dates YYYY/MM/DD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort ordering you've shown is actually correct. The problem is that you're sorting strings rather than dates. If possible, populate the `date` property with instances of `NSDate` rather than instances of `NSString`, and then the sort will do what you expect.

If for some reason you can't use `NSDate` instances in the `date` property (which would seem a little odd, but who knows), you can instead sort the array by sending it a `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` message, and passing in a block that defines your custom sort.

Comment: actually I've tried using sortedArrayUsingComparator:caseInsensitiveCompare but it doesn't work too.. hmm..

Comment: It's not clear what you're saying. `caseInsensitiveCompare:` is a method, not a block. The `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method requires a block as an argument. If you're unfamiliar with blocks, here's a link to Apple's [Blocks Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) guide. But changing the underlying property type to `NSDate` would be a better (and simpler) solution to your problem than implementing a custom comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is working correctly, as it is comparing only string. So you would firstly require to convert NSDate to NSString and then do sort operation on NSDate, and revert back to sorted string array of dates as below:

```
- (NSArray *) sortArrayOfDateStrings:(NSArray*)array {

NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
NSMutableArray *sortedDateArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
NSDate *dateObject;

for(NSString *dateString in array){

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];

[sortedArray addObject:dateFromString];
}

NSSortDescriptor *dateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"date" ascending: YES];
[sortedDateArray addObjectsFromArray:[sortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject: dateSortDescriptor]]];

[sortedArray removeAllObjects];

for (NSDate* sortedDate in sortedDateArray){

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sortedDate];
NSLog(@"%@", strDate);
[dateFormatter release];

[sortedArray addObject:strDate];
}

return sortedArray
}
```

Comment: The OP's question wasn't how to sort an array of strings, it was how to sort an array of objects based on a date property.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. But still in that case, above logic will be implemented, just with the change in fast enum object NSString to  NSDictionary or any relative K-V object...